# Remove randomly generated(?) numbers from .zsh_history file

Tags: osx, zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

Whenever I open my `.zsh_history` I always get these numbers:

```
: 1563741867:0;zsh --version
: 1563741874:0;ls
: 1563741883:0;cd Desktop
: 1563741888:0;cd ..
: 1563741892:0;ls -a
: 1563741927:0;open .zshrc
```

Comment: They're probably timestamps. Does it matter that they're in there?

Comment: They are in fact unix timestamps. Use this site to convert: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: I'd prefer it if they were human readable timestamps.. How would I go about having them converted so they'd become human readable *in* .zsh_history?

Comment: Not familiar with zsh, but presumably if you enter `history` as command that will show the timestamps in human readable form?

Comment: maybe related https://serverfault.com/q/114988/481846

Comment: Thanks! Inputting ``unsetopt EXTENDED_HISTORY``, closing the terminal and .zsh_history, and reopening them did the trick and removed the Unix timestamps.
Although I'm interested in knowing if I could replace these with human readable timestamps like the ones in ``history -i`` or ``history -E``.

Answer (score 3):

That number is clearly not randomly generated: if it was, the numbers wouldn't be in order and close together. It's actually a timestamp in the standard Unix format, which is the number of seconds since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (1970-01-01).

```
% date -d @1563741867
Sun Jul 21 22:44:27 CEST 2019
```

The second number (always 0 in your examples) is the amount of time during which the command ran (more precisely, the time until the next prompt — time spent after a command gets backgrounded doesn't count).

The presence of these two numbers is controlled by the option [`extended_history`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fHISTORY), which is off by default. If you remove `setopt extended_history` from your `.zshrc`, and restart zsh, these numbers will go away when zsh writes new history entries. If you use a framework such as oh-my-zsh which turns this option on for you, either find out how to configure it or add `unsetopt extended_history` after loading the framework.

There's no way to use a different syntax for the timestamps. That would be pretty pointless: it's an internal storage format, meant only for zsh to read back, not for direct human consumption. If you want to see the times, the normal way to do it is to run the [`fc` or `history` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc) with an option to print the timestamp, e.g.

```
history -i
```